# How to get information of Publisher,InstalledON,Size information of the softwares installed in system

Tags: c#

For getting the software names the below program is OK

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");

foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine(mo["Version"]);

}

 Console.ReadKey(true);
```

But what if I want to get Publisher,InstalledON,Size information of those softwares.. How can I get those?

Comment: Win32_Product will only list software installed using MSI's. Just so you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `mo["InstallDate"]` and `mo["Vendor"]` - I can't seem to find any Size but you could use `mo["InstallLocation"]` and add the size of its content up (for example using [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) anf [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx))